# Setting a property on a widget using configuration

Tags: java, android, android-widget

First I have defined a widget for the front end. I have two quick questions

I add this to the manifest xml

```
    <receiver android:name=".Widget" android:label="My Widget">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget" />
    </receiver>
```

This should load the configuration class when its added to the front end. It doesn't show up in the widget list anymore. Since changing the action to APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE

```
    <appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="146dip" 
    android:minHeight="146dip"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="0" 
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget" 
    android:configure="com.deliveryninja.yourclock.configuration.Configure" 
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
   />
```

That is the xml for the widget. Currently I'm just using a simple clock.

Now in the configuration class I populate a WidgetModel and add the path of a clock face to the shared attributes.

I want to use the configuration class to get the path, and then update the widget.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Widget" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:gravity="center">
    <AnalogClock android:id="@+id/AnalogClock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hand_hour="@drawable/widgethour"
        android:hand_minute="@drawable/widgetminute" 

    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to be able to set the android:dial property to the path of the given resource which the user has selected.

This is where i'm struggling, how do I set a propery on the AttributeSet and either add a new AnalogClock to the widget using RemoteViews or how do I edit the property of the existing AnalogClock in the widget xml.

```
public static void updateOne(Context context, int appWidgetId){
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

    WidgetModel widgetData = WidgetModel.getWidgetData(context, appWidgetId);
    widgetData.getClockFacePath();
    AnalogClock clock = new AnalogClock(context);

    AttributeSet attributes = new //?? how do i make the AttributeSet


    //RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
    //views.setString(R.id.AnalogClock, , value)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

firstly, android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE belongs in the  that does the configuring, not in the  for the widget

unfortunately RemoteViews are very limited in what they can do.  I've had to resort to doing a lot of things by drawing into a Bitmap and then having a simple widget that just displays that bitmap (updated via RemoteViews)

Comment: I had a thought that I could do this by extending the AnalogClock class and exposing setters and getters for the drawable resources. I got a snipet of code from another question which will take a url and create a drawable resource from that. Then its just a case of creating a new MyClock and using the setters. Hopefully that should work.